# PHP include a file at subdomain from main domain on a different server/host

Tags: php, include, server-side-includes

I have this php

```
www.example.com/template.php
```

and would like to include it in a index.php file at

```
sub.example.com/index.php
```

and this sub-domain is on a different server with a different host.
Please advice.

Comment: /path/to/index.php so like /www/public_html/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the file contents into a php file then include that,

```
$url = "http://sub.example.com/index.php";
$file = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents('index.php', $file);
include index.php;
```

I'd recommend changing the name from index.php tho, and make sure the php file isn't being parsed first when you getting it.

There is also nothing safe about this.

Edit:  Another option,

There is a php.ini option called allow_url_include.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php